# Add data to the report in data from SQL. Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, datatables, report

In my factory, we have some system to print label with our production. So, that system, was made on Microsoft Access. It is very easy. I have form, after that i will take data from tables, and after that i will make report to print. But, I have some problem. First, labels on our products have serial numbers:

[image]

Like that:

[image]

And, every country, when we send our products, requires labels with serial number and with some element. For example in Hungary, we have our serial number 04-DoP-TL45A-2015-EN and that element: "/HU". So, in result, we must have: 04-DoP-TL45A-2015-EN/HU.
To every country, we have some report, with their language. I add in report simple text. Like that:

[image]

TThat is working. But, when i choose other product, that has shortest serial number, i have a big space. Like that:
04-DoP-TL45A-2015-EN         /HU 
And my question: How add data to the report in data from SQL ?
It serial number was taken from the sql, and when i selected a REPORT for country Hungary, added to it an element with the code of the country.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having two textboxes, one for the S/N and one for the country code, have one textbox (that you already use for the S/N) and concatenate the two fields:

```
=[SerialNumber] & [CountryCode]
```

and use that expression as the control source for the textbox.